# Postgres : Query in Idle Transaction State

Tags: java, database, hibernate, postgresql, transactions

I am using Postgres 9.4 with hibernate , recently my server load has been increased then I checked server statistics using  [pg_stat_activity](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/monitoring-stats.html) command.

It shows multiple `queries` in **Idle Transaction State** , since `1day , 2days` etc .

Can anyone explain that which `transaction` this statistics indicating , my `Hibernate Transaction` or another?

Answer (score 0):

This [article](http://www.depesz.com/2008/08/28/hunting-idle-in-transactions/) might help you. It's a [Perl script](https://github.com/depesz/pgsql-tools/blob/master/find-iit-connections.pl) that parses the PostgreDQL log and gives you a summary of how long it took each statement, so you can pinpoint what the user was doing in the **Idle Transactions**.